# Does Core Data support VIEW in SQLite?

Tags: core-data, join, sqlite

Would like to know if Core Data support creating a [VIEW](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html) in sqlite3 database?

If does not, is the JOIN the only way I can select the data from two tables (each of them has different table structure) ?

Answer (score 0):

Directly from API you can't. Core Data is object storage, not database - even if it's sqlite behind. 
Anyway, you can open your CoreData database as standard sqlite and make direct queries on stored data. DB structure is very easy to understand.